# Convert Array to Object with keys in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have an array of objects,

```
    [
      [
        {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0},
        {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0},
        {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0}
      ],
      [
        {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0},
        {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0},
        {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0}
      ],
      [
        {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0},
        {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0},
        {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0}
      ],
      [
        {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0},
        {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0},
        {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0}
      ],
]
```

I need to convert this to object with keys like

```
{
  "1": {
     "1": {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0}, 
     "2": {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0},
     "3": {"m": 4, "p": 1, "r": 0, "t": 0}
  },
  .......

}
```

I used the below code but getting parse error,

```
$ss= json_decode(json_encode($obj1));
$ss1=(Object)(array_filter($ss));
echo json_encode($ss1);
```

Please help

Regards,
Rekha

Comment: _but getting parse error_ What is the error exactly saying?

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']' in C:\wamp64\www\testobj.php on line 9

Comment: _on line 9..._ which is line 9?

Comment: So you want to increase all the keys in the JSON by one?

Comment: remove the last "**,**" from your JSON

Comment: the closest you can get to is: `echo json_encode($ss, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);` provided your JSON string is indeed a valid one. :p